# X fails to start after update with reboot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, updates, xorg

After an update that included the kernel and a reboot, X no longer started for my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  An attempt to `startx` manually failed as well with this message:

[image: screen shot]

Note: the underlying issue has been addressed by a more general question and answer and is linked in my answer below.

Comment: @Pilot6, I think it is not a duplicate but a special case with more detail on that case.  When I ran into the problem, I initially searched for terms that would have led me here; I found your more general question/answer only after looking more carefully at my output and logs.

Comment: There are lots of these "special cases". No 3rd party modules are loaded with SB enabled. Nothing is special with Nvidia.

Comment: @Pilot6, the specific ([special](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/special)) case I am addressing is that "X no longer starts," the problem I had.  Having this question/answer may help some people find a solution _faster_.  Do you have a suggestion what I could improve?

Comment: The answer is good. But it is not surprising that X does not start when `nvidia` is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352': Required key not available
```

had the right clue.  In a nutshell, the new kernel appears to not load unsigned third party modules (the Nvidia driver in my case).  **Disabling Secure Boot** in the UEFI (BIOS) settings solved the problem.  This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/764417/388964) helped me disable Secure Boot for my ASUS board a little faster.

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/388964) has good background, a possible alternative solution, and mentions the problem starts with kernel 4.4.0-20.  In my case (Ubuntu 14.04), the kernel that caused problems is 3.16.0-77.